# Show defaulted text in a share button?

Tags: html, button, share

I was wondering if it was possible to show some pre-defined text when pressing a tweet and google+ button. 
I know this is possible for facebook but i couldn't find any usable code for the google+ button.

The code i've got for my facebook share button (is already working) is:

```
<a title="send to Facebook"
 href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=EHBE Groningen&p[summary]=this is the text to share http://sharelink.com&p[url]=www.example.nl&p[images][0]=example_image"
 target="_blank">
 <span>
  <img width="14" height="14" src="'icons/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" /> Facebook 
 </span>
</a>
```

The code i currently got for my tweet button (also working) is :

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/?status=text to tweet" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','http://twitter.com']);" target="_blank">Tweet over deze pagina</a>
```

so my question is if it's possible to show pre-defined text when liking, sharing or tweeting a page or article for some sort of google + button.

EDIT

---

I want to be able to change the text that appears when you actually click the button. So the button itself is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it how facebook and twitter provide, from what I can gather looking at their [Snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/).

What you can do, is this:

```
<!-- Update your html tag to include the itemscope and itemtype attributes. -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<!-- Add the following three tags inside head. -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="my title">
<meta itemprop="description" content="a description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://my-url.com/logo.png">
```

I realise this is probably going to be a pain if your content is loaded via `AJAX`. In that case, you could do something like:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">my title</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://my-url.com/logo.png" />
  <p itemprop="description">a description</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of the itemprops on the meta tags you can use Open Graph meta tags. http://ogp.me/

Comment: @BWRic this was the code given the Snippet documentation, if OP follows the link it recommends **Open Graph protocol** as it's second recommended choice.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

Read and add those tags / codes.

Comment: I dont think you get my question, I want to be able to change the text that appears when you actually click the button. So the button itself is fine.